# Why are NSTableView and NSOutlineView so slow with Yosemite? Any workaround?

Tags: nstableview, osx-yosemite, nsoutlineview

In Yosemite MacOS 10.10 (including 10.10.0, 10.10.1 and 10.10.2) performances of these 2 classes (NSTableView and NSOutlineView) show very bad performances compared to Mavericks (10.9). I tried to convert them to Core Animation (enabling layer-backing): performances are a bit better, but still very bad. When 'sampling' the application, MacOS spends 99% in MacOS functions (CALayer drawInContext, CALayer display, ...).

Any workaround to this problem? It seems to affect any applications that uses NSOutlineView and NSTableView.

Comment: Does it affect all of your table and outline views or just some?